# Trying to set values in a second class for overload methods in first class?

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

I am new to java and am currently creating a program where I calculate various amounts of money (tax, gross pay, etc) using overload methods and then display it. I have completed the bulk of it (I think), but now I need to create a second class in the same package where I set values to the first program to see if it works. I have no idea how to call the method when overload methods are involved, I tried to use get and set but I don't know how to apply that in the overload method. I apologize if my terminology is off, I'm still quite new!

```
package payrolllibrary;

public class PayrollLibrary {

       public static float calculatePay(float hours, float rates)
       {System.out.println("Pay: " + rates*hours);
       return 0;
       }

       public static float calculatePay(float hours, float rates, float multiplier)
        {System.out.println("Pay: " + rates*hours*multiplier);
       return 0;
       }      

       public static float calculateGrossPay(float regularPay, float overtimePay, float shift2Pay, float shift3Pay, float weeklyPay)
       {float grossPay;
       grossPay = regularPay + overtimePay + shift2Pay + shift3Pay + weeklyPay;
       System.out.println("Gross Pay: " + grossPay);
       return 0;
       }

       public static float calculatedSocialSecurityTax(float grossPay, float ytdEarnings, float ytdSocialSecurity)
       {
           float calculateSocialSecurityTax = 0;
           float calculateGrossPay = 0;

           if(ytdEarnings > 118500)
               {calculateSocialSecurityTax = 0;}
           if (ytdEarnings+calculateGrossPay < 118500)
               {calculateSocialSecurityTax = calculateGrossPay*.062f;}
           if (ytdEarnings+calculateGrossPay > 118500)
                {if (calculateGrossPay*.062 <= 118500)
                {calculateSocialSecurityTax = 118500;}               
                }
           {System.out.println("Social Security Tax: " + calculateSocialSecurityTax);
           return 0;
           }
       }

       public static float calculateMedicareTax(float grossPay)
       {float medicareTax;
       medicareTax = grossPay*.0145f;
       System.out.println("Medicare Tax: " + medicareTax);
       return 0;
       }

       public static float calculateStateTax(float grossPay, float stateWithholding)
       {System.out.println("State Tax: " + grossPay*stateWithholding);
       return 0;
       }

       public static float calculateNetPay(float grossPay, float federalWithholding, float socialSecurityWithholding, float medicareWithholding, float stateWithholding, float deduction1Amount, float deduction2Amount, float deduction3Amount)
       {float calculateNetPay;
       calculateNetPay = grossPay-federalWithholding-socialSecurityWithholding-medicareWithholding-stateWithholding-deduction1Amount-deduction2Amount-deduction3Amount;
       System.out.println("Net Pay: " + calculateNetPay);
       return 0;
       }

       public static float calculateDeduction(float grossPay, char deductionCode, float deductionValue)
       {if (deductionCode == 'N')
       {deductionValue = 0;}
       else if (deductionCode == 'F')
       {deductionValue = deductionValue;}
       else if (deductionCode == 'P')
       {deductionValue = deductionValue*grossPay;} 
       System.out.println("Deduction: " + deductionValue);
       return 0;
   }
}




package PayrollLibrary;

public class TestPayroll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PayrollLibrary Person = new PayrollLibrary();
        Person.setRate(99.99);
        Person.setHours(99);
        Person.setMultiplier(999);
        Person.setRegularPay(999);
        Person.setOvertimePay(999);
        Person.setShift2Pay(999);
        Person.setShift3Pay(999);
        Person.setWeekendPay(999);
        Person.setYtdEarnings(999);
        Person.setYtdSocialSecurity(999);
        Person.setStateWithholding(999);
        Person.setDeduction1Amount(999);
        Person.setDeduction2Amount(999);
        Person.setDeduction3Amount(999);
        Person.setDeductionCode('F');
        Person.setDeductionAmount(999);


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post up the complete `PayrollLibrary` code? The setters you're calling in the main method don't exist in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Those `setXXX()` won't set the values just because their English meaning are so. They are just names of methods. To set the values you have to code them. So in your `PayrollLibrary` you should have

```
public class PayrollLibrary {
    float rate;
    float hours;
    ......
    public void setRate(float inRate) {
        this.rate = inRate;
    }
    public void setHours(float inHours) {
        this.hours = inHours;
    }
```

Then in your calculation methods, if what you going to use are `rate` and `hours`, you don't have to pass them to the method, simply:

```
public float calculatePay() {
    return rate*hours;
}
```

So in your `main()`, do this:

```
PayrollLibrary person = new PayrollLibrary();
person.setRate(99.99f);
person.setHours(99.0f);
```

to obtain the pay right after the `setXXX` above, do this:

```
float thePay = person.calculatePay();
```

Please note the Java convention: class names starts in upper case, variable and method names start in lower case.

Hope it helps.